# How to create a website where people have to pay to see the content of some pages?

Tags: paypal

I want to create a website where users have full access to each page only if they pay me a fee.

I don't know how to read a credit card, I would like to use paypal or something similar, but how ?

And I would need to pay some taxes or something because I'm getting money ?

Note: I'm not in US, I`m from Romania) ?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a combination of Paypal and a DBMS. The work flow would be as such:

1. Your customer should fill out a form, such as desired username and password.
2. Your customer clicks a link that directs them to PayPal, or fills out their credit card information on your site ([using Website Payments Pro)](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPWebsitePaymentsPro).
3. Process transactions using PayPal's API. Here are some helpful
   developer links:

   [API Integration Summary](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_overview)
      [PayPal API Reference](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_reference)
4. Depending on your integration, PayPal will return with a `SUCCESS` or `FAILURE` if your customer's payment was verified.
5. Depending on your integration, upon success, you can extract customer information,
   such as name, address, etc. and save it into your DBMS, including the customer's username and password.
6. Now, whenever the customer re-visits your site, validate the customer by asking for their username/password.

Since you will only store customer credentials if the payment was verified, customers will only see pages if they have paid.

Without more specifics about your understanding of a web dev language, DBMS, PayPal, login/registering implementations, this could only be a general outline.